# Как сохранить store redux в localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Добрый день, подскажите, как добавить store redux в localstorage (на данный момент обнуляется при перезагрузке):
store:

```
     function configureStore(initialState) {
let createStoreWithMiddleware;

const middleware = process.env.__DEV__
    ? applyMiddleware(thunk, createLogger())
    : applyMiddleware(thunk);

createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
    middleware,
);

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(createStore, loadState())(rootReducer, initialState);

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot
        .accept('../reducer', () => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('../reducer/index');
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
        });
}



store.subscribe(() => {
    saveState(store.getState().albums)
});

return store;
```

}
export default configureStore

Comment: кажется вам могли бы помочь redux-persist и redux-offline

Comment: самый просто вариант это конечно написать свой middleware

Answer (score 1):

В первом приближении кажется так. Пишем middleware и подключаем. Но в целом я бы посмотрел в сторону redux-persist, redux-offline или других отработанных решений, так как тут как всегда много подводных камней

Кстати в вашем коде несколько непонятно как подключается middleware, зачем там compose, если в нём только одна функция. Если некие middleware нужно фильтровать, вот вариант как это сделать может быть несколько более элегантно. Также советую переименовать `__DEV__` обратно в `NODE_ENV`, так как библиотеки (react), а также утилиты (npm, yarn, webpack) ожидают `NODE_ENV=production` при продакш сборке.

```
const persistMiddleware = ({ getState(), dispatch }) => next => action => {
    const result = next(action);
    localStorage.set('my-state', JSON.stringify(getState());
    return result;
}

const middleware = [
    thunk,
    process.env.__DEV__&& createLogger,
    persistMiddleware,
].Boolean();

const initialState = localStorage.getItem('my-state') || {};

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
```